# How to access injected services in partial DbContext OnConfiguring?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core

When scaffolding a DbContext with `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold`, the tool generates a partial class. I then create another partial implementation of the DbContext to implement OnConfiguring (need to pass `--no-onconfiguring`).

However, now I want to access a service from DI inside the OnConfiguring method, namely IHttpContextAccessor.

What I would do when using a code first approach (without the partial classes) is inject the IHttpContextAccessor in the constructor of the DbContext, store it in a private readonly field and use it in the OnConfiguring method.

This seemingly also works with the partial DbContext. I only had to make the field nullable because the empty constructor generated by the scaffolding didn't assign it, giving a warning.

My full implementation looks like this:

```cs
// Partial DbContext generated by scaffolding
public partial class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext(DbContextOptions<SitraDriversContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    // Rest of the scaffolded context ...
}

// My partial DbContext
public partial class MyContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor? _httpContextAccessor;

    public SitraDriversContext(
        DbContextOptions<SitraDriversContext> options,
        IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        : base(options)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        // Use HttpContext to determine connection string
    }
}
```

My question is simply if this is the correct way to go about this? I'm confused as to how DI chooses the right constructor in this case.

I also saw that DbContext has a method named GetService but when I tried using it in OnConfiguring, I got an exception saying the context is not fully configured yet.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want this, specifically `IHttpContextAccessor` ? If you want to create a multitenant application, the information you need to pass is the tenant, not the HTTP request. There may not be an active HTTP request at all when you try to talk to the database. In the [EF Core multitenancy docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/multitenancy) an `ITenantService` is used that allows your *controller* or middleware code to set the tenant

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos This looks very similar to what I am doing right now, which is reading the HttpHeaders and determining which connection string I need to use based on a specific header. I'm confused how you'd set the Tenant using this solution though.

Comment: It's not similar at all, because there's no HttpContext without a request, it ties you with something that's three levels away from your data layer *and* makes testing a lot harder.

Comment: Besides, what happens when you realize you need to validate those headers so tenants don't read other tenants' data just by changing a header in Chrome? Or that the tenant identity should be retrieved from a user's profile, not what they sent in the request? Would you put JWT and claims processing in your data layer ?

Comment: Those are valid concerns. I'll evaluate the solution you provided.